# Site stored locally takes long to load - External resource failing to load

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, external

As weird as this may sound, my website is stored on my localhost and it's taking forever to load. Actually, it never finishes. My website is using Bootstrap 3 for the front-end and the back-end is written in PHP.

This never happened before and I'm unable to find the roots of this problem, but the way my website starting behaving this morning really caught me in surprise. I use some external libraries to power up my website, such as the Javascript libraries to have HTML5 run on IE, Facebook/Twitter/Google+ like buttons and nothing else that may depend on something from the outside.

I've opened up the console in Google Chrome and saw this:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < www.sourcecrab.com/:1

So this is basically failing to load I suspect, causing all this havoc in my website, which is still attempting to load up while I'm trying to post this question.

I've tried searching around for this error, but got nothing returned. Any information to help me find and kill this problem would be appreciated.

I'm using XAMPP on Windows 8.1 to run my local websites.

Comment: Perhaps the 'Net' tab of Firebug (or something similar in Chrome) can give you more insight on what it's trying to load?

Comment: did u restart server?

Comment: I did. The bad part is that my site wont even show up anymore at all, so I can't actually see the "Network" tab in Chrome!

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers? Seems there's a bigger fault if you cant even open the net tab in Chrome.